# Use Reader Literals In Other Projects

Tags: clojure

I have my reader literals in the `data_readers.clj` file for my project and things work fine. If I create a new project, can I use the reader literals I created in the dependant library? I don't see a way to use/require reader literals.

For example, if I have a `data_readers.clj` file:

```
{ml/foo mylib.core.foo}
```

Can I do `#ml/foo some-arg` from a separate project?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways after requiring library:

1) bind `*data-readers*`

```
(ns mylib.core)
(def foo identity)
(binding [*data-readers* (assoc *data-readers* 'ml/foo mylib.core/foo)]
  (read-string "#ml/foo arg")) ;;=> arg
```

Besides, you can bind `*default-data-reader-fn*` for all tags. see [example](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*default-data-reader-fn*)

Pro: local impact, advised way as both vars marked dynamic.
Contra: doesn't work with `clojure.edn`

2) alter `clojure.core/default-data-readers`

```
(alter-var-root #'clojure.core/default-data-readers assoc 'ml/foo mylib.core/foo)
(clojure.edn/read-string "#ml/foo arg") ;;=> arg
(read-string "#ml/foo arg")             ;;=> arg
```

Pro: works with `clojure.edn`.
Contra: global mutation